# How can we concur that night of power "Laylat Al Qadr" occurs every year?

Tags: ramadan, laylat-al-qadr

In this last days of holy month Ramadan there is a lot of telling about Night of Power.
My question is how do we concurred (know) that "Laylat Al Qadr" occurs every Ramadan.

Comment: are you asking if it happens every year, or if it truley happens during ramadan? because it obviously hapeens every year its a date like a birthday or holiday, it hapens every year

Comment: @NesreenA I am asking does it hapeens every year, I know that is obviously for most of us, I just wonder how we made that conclusion. I beleive in night of power and I pray this is not provocative question just wondering

Comment: what if i asked you if my birthday truley happened every year, how do i come up with that conclusion?

Comment: im just trying to point out that dates are on a set time and they re-occur

Comment: @NesreenA What If I ask you if does lunar eclipse or eclipse of the sun or Judgment Day :)

Answer (score 3):

As you can see below the verse 44:4 (in bold) refers to the Laylat al-Qadr:

> وَالْكِتَابِ الْمُبِينِ
>
> By the clear Book,
>
> إِنَّا أَنزَلْنَاهُ فِي لَيْلَةٍ مُّبَارَ‌كَةٍ ۚ إِنَّا كُنَّا مُنذِرِ‌ينَ
>
> Indeed, We sent it down during a blessed night. Indeed, We were to warn [mankind].
>
> **فِيهَا يُفْرَ‌قُ كُلُّ أَمْرٍ‌ حَكِيمٍ**
>
> On that night **is made distinct** every precise matter
>
> [[Ad-Dukhan: 2-4]](http://quran.com/44/2-4)

And because of the present tense of the word "**is made distinct( يُفْرَ‌قُ )**", we believe that the Laylat al-Qadr do occur every year.

**Reference:**

- [Tafsir al-Mizan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tafsir_al-Mizan)

Answer (score 2):

We know from many ahadith that laylatul al qadr happends during ramdan:

> Sahih Bukhari : Volume 3, Book 32 "Taraweeh", Number 238
>
> Narrated ‘Ibn Abbas (Radi Allah Anha): The Allah’s Messenger (sal-allahu- alleihi-wasallam ) said:
>   “Look for the Night of Qadr in the last ten nights of Ramazan on the night when nine or seven or five nights remain out of the last ten nights of the Ramazan.”

As we know, ramdan occurs every hijri year, and if laylatul qadar hapends in ramdan, then it must occur every hijri year too.

Although we may not know the exact date of laylatul qadr we know for sure that it happens every year.